# Jquery.prepend() removes last inserted value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple insertion with Jquery, and everything works fine
The only problem is that after the first insertion, the new object overwrites the last inserted one

```
function insert_note(note_data){
    console.log(note_data);
    var note_object = {}

    note_data.forEach(function(item){
        note_object[item.name] = item.value;
    });

    console.log(note_object);
    note_layout = $(note_layout);
    note_layout.find('span').text(note_object.note_title);
    note_layout.find('p').text(note_object.note_content);
    note_layout.attr('data-id', note_object.note_id);

    $('#notes_container').prepend(note_layout);
```

And this is the note_layout saved in a js variable. Everytime I'm modifying it with the infos I get from the user and attach it to the DOM with prepend():

```
    <div class="row" data-id="">
      <div class="col l8 push-l2 s10 push-s1">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title"></span>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat" data-action="set_as_done">Set as done</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat" data-action="postpone">Postpone</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Am I missing to consider something ?
Thx in advance !

Comment: What is initial value of `note_layout`?

Comment: Using prepend on already existing object in DOM just moves it. You propably want to prepend its clone. If i get it, you want: `$('#notes_container').prepend(note_layout.clone());` or maybe better: `note_layout = $(note_layout).clone();`

Comment: Exact, but what I;m doing is create every time a new object, in fact the one that I've posted is stored in a js variable, and everytime I'm attaching a new one to the DOM. I forgot to say this in the question

Comment: @AndreaTulimiero What do you mean by 'create a new object'? If you refer to this: `note_layout = $(note_layout);` It doesn't create a new object and i'm really not sure the purpose of this line btw. Like Shaunak asked: `What is initial value of note_layout?`

Comment: I've stored the 'html' of the object in a variable called note_layout, and everytime I'm creating a Jquery object from it using $(note_layout)

Comment: Your question is missing context but using `note_layout = $(note_layout);`, now on next call, `note_layout` will be equal to `$(note_layout)`, no more former `note_layout` variable. You should really post MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by A. Wolff, you are reusing the same note_layout after the first call, which is then moving the object, not creating a new one.  You can fix this by never changing note_layout, and creating a new variable to hold the DOM object you are creating from it, and inserting that.

Change:

```
console.log(note_object);
note_layout = $(note_layout);
note_layout.find('span').text(note_object.note_title);
note_layout.find('p').text(note_object.note_content);
note_layout.attr('data-id', note_object.note_id);

$('#notes_container').prepend(note_layout);
```

to

```
console.log(note_object);
var note_layout2 = $(note_layout);
note_layout2.find('span').text(note_object.note_title);
note_layout2.find('p').text(note_object.note_content);
note_layout2.attr('data-id', note_object.note_id);

$('#notes_container').prepend(note_layout2);
```